# UART / GPIO bridge (bitbang)?

Tags: usb, switches, uart, gpio

I like to control 8 switches (GPIO pins) individually via USB (on/off). To start i have a USB UART adapter (CP2102). By sending a command to the virtual port to control each pin i would like to control each pin.

My question is, how do i bridge from UART to 8 GPIO pins? Is there any IC that could do this?

Or are there better ways of doing this via USB?

*I know i can easily do this with a Arduino and a shift register, but i would like to make this truly low budget, with a minimum of overhead.*

Answer (score 2):

Use an USB converter chip like the FT245R that has an 8-bit parallel output instead of an asynchronous serial output.

Answer (score 0):

There is an IC that does exactly that...the UART. A UART converts parallel data to serial and vice-versa. Use an RS232-to-TTL voltage converter to get the serial data back to normal logic levels, and then let a standard UART perform the serial-to-parallel conversion. The old Intersil 6402 would be great for this but I'm sure there are others that you could use as well.

Comment: Thank you @Joe Hass. But a 'Intersil 6402' seems pretty expensive (and carries quiet some overhead?)?

Comment: Maybe you should have been more specific about what you meant when you said "low budget". The 6402 is certainly cheaper than an Arduino.

Comment: Thank you, and your right, i didn't give a budget bandwidth. 6402 @ Farnell is +/- 20 EUR. The 2102 i bought for less then 3 USD. Im looking for a *simple* bridge -if possible- for under 3 USD. Since it *seems* such a simple thing, i thought there would be a cheap IC that could bridge from UART to GPIO.